# High Level Docker and Dockerfile Volume/writeout understanding

Tags: maven, docker, junit, dockerfile, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm working on a maven project and running tests using Junit within this project. I'm new to docker and I'm trying to write a Dockerfile that generates an image that creates a container that when run, executes the tests and outputs the XML results found in `target/failsafe-reports` (output folder of a maven plugin that summarizes the results of the Junit tests). I've been attempting this using links like [Dockerfile Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and [Manage Data in Containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/). My mentor wrote a line that achieves this using `docker run -it --rm --name containerName -v "$PWD":/usr/src/tests -v /Users/theUser/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/tests maven:3.5-alpine mvn clean verify`.

The above line line is called in the root of my project (in the location where the pom and the Dockerfile are) so `$PWD` refers to the root of my project.

My question is how much of this work can be automated in a Dockerfile? In my attempts with using and running a Dockerfile I haven't been able to get anything written out when having the current Dockerfile.

```
FROM maven:3.5-alpine

COPY ["./", "/usr/local/tests"]

VOLUME /usr/local/tests/target/failsafe-reports

ENTRYPOINT mvn -f /usr/local/tests/pom.xml verify
```

I build it with
`docker build . -t imageName`

and create the container with
`docker run -it --rm --name test-container -v "$PWD":/usr/local/tests -v /Users/theUser/.m2:/root/.m2 imageName`

This seems to run my tests but doesn't write out the results into my local file system. What concept(s) of docker and Dockerfiles am I missing?

Comment: Edited what my dockerfile is, and I've narrowed the problem down to something dealing with write permissions, as my local target folder is changed from my run command but none of the contents in the target folder are changed (during the test run, a folder in target is made and destroyed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running just:

```
docker run -d --name test-container -v $PWD:/usr/local/tests -v /Users/theUser/.m2:/root/.m2 imageName
```

Then check in your host's local current folder (pwd) is the output was created.

If not, then get into the container by bring up a shell using:

```
docker exec -it test-container sh
```

Now you should be at the prompt, try to run `ls -l` or look around to `find` where & whether the output was created inside the container. That should give you clues as to what to volume mount or to fix the process itself if it did not generate the output files.

Comment: The host does not have data written out, but there is changed data within the container, now attempting to work on how to access that data in the volume

Comment: Yes, you can also run `docker diff test-container` from the host and that should show all the files that were changed. Then all you need to do is to use `-v` to bind mount that folder to an empty folder on your host and you should get your output data.